# getting sum of item quantities grouped by item groups

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have the following data:

| LOC | ITEM | GROUP | MONTH | PCS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | A1 | A | 01/01/2022 | 8 |
| Y | A1 | A | 01/01/2022 | 76 |
| Z | A1 | A | 01/01/2022 | 11 |
| X | A2 | A | 01/01/2022 | 9 |
| Y | A2 | A | 01/01/2022 | 19 |
| Z | A2 | A | 01/01/2022 | 13 |

I need to get the sum of PCS  for each LOC/ MONTH summed by GROUP

My tentative query so far is:

```
QUERY(DATA;"SELECT LOC,ITEM,GROUP,SUM(PCS) WHERE LOC='X' AND GROUP='A' AND MONTH='01/01/2022' GROUP BY LOC,GROUP,MONTH,PCS";1)
```

My expected results is:

| LOC | GROUP | MONTH | PCS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 01/01/2022 | 17 |

the test spreadsheet with data, formula results is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q8Rx7pAmlYyjHFKfVJF6XBvqivlFUQ8qi34XkBTuI58/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(DATA;
 "SELECT A,C,D,SUM(E) 
  WHERE A='"&SEL_L&"' 
    AND C='"&SEL_G&"' 
    AND D = date '"&TEXT(SEL_M; "e-m-d")&"' GROUP BY A,C,D"; 1)
```